# Store a state inside a Controller class

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing a Web API service with C# with a console using Nuget Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin.

I don't know if it is possible to store a state inside a `Controller` class or if I need, as someone has suggested in the comments, to inject another class that will manage that state. The following is only an example because the question is about how to manage the state of a client (if that client has assigned a task or not, or if it has ended its previous task) when they ask for another task.

This web service will have a method where clients can ask for a task. The code for this method looks something like that:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleWebDriver.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class TaskController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get(string workerName)
        {
            if ((workerName == null) || (workerName.Equals(string.Empty)))
                return Ok("Empty");
            else
                return Ok(workerName);
        }
    }
}
```

Inside `Get` method I will need to check if that `workerName` has assigned a task and, if it is not, assign one a store it. My problem is that I don't know what do I have to do to keep a structure in memory while the service is up.

I don't know if I have to declare a, for example, a dictionary inside the controller or inside `startup` class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace ConsoleWebDriver
{
    internal class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I think that structure has to be a concurrent one.

What do I have to do to keep that information in memory while the service is up?

Comment: Please be careful when selecting tags, don't just write a single letter and press `Enter`. That usually select the wrong tag. Like the C language tag instead of C#.

Comment: You may want to create a service for managing tasks, then inject it into the controller.

Comment: @BradyDean OK. I'm going to search for what is a "service for managing tasks", and then how to "inject it into the controller".

Comment: Is ANYbody able to call the endpoint? Is a user able to only retrieve HIS tasks, or is there only one list of tasks? If there's only one list of tasks, Brady Dean's comment is what you need: `services.AddSingleton<ITaskStateService, TaskStateService>();`. Beware that the asp.net core application may go to hibernation after 5 minutes, and the state will be lost

Comment: Do the tasks live in the application or are they offloaded externally?  If they are external, you shouldn't store any state in your application unless you can also restore that state from an external resource, since it can be lost at any time.

Comment: I guess I'm confused by what you are asking. What structure are you trying to keep in memory? Are you saving each worker and whether it has been assigned a task? In that case you should use a database. Your endpoint can get the workername and check the database to see if it has a task assigned. If not, it could check the list of tasks and pick the first one which hasn't been assigned yet.

Comment: No, I'm only asking if I can store a state inside a `Controller` class. It is only an example.